# Is it better to have a public readonly object, identical local readonly objects per class, or to directly reference a library object?

Tags: c#

I'm building a game using C# in XNA and I'm not sure which of these four ways is best to refer to the "Viewport" for reading access only:

1. Have a public static variable that every class can access by calling Game.Viewport (Game is the main class:

   public static readonly Viewport Viewport = GraphicsDevice.Viewport;

in use:

```
rectangle = new Rectangle (Game.Viewport/2, ...
```

1. Have a local variable that refers to the Viewport for each class that needs the viewport:

   private readonly Viewport viewport = GraphicsDevice.Viewport;

in use:

```
rectangle = new Rectangle (viewport/2, ...
```

1. Use a local variable passed down into the constructor of each class that needs the viewport (this would be the only one that didn't require imported Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics):

   private readonly Viewport viewport;

then in the constructor:

```
viewport = pViewport;
```

in use:

```
rectangle = new Rectangle (viewport/2, ...
```

1. Directly reference the viewport from the class library everywhere where it's needed (in use):

   rectangle = new Rectangle (GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width/2, ...

I wondering which one is best in terms of speed and which one is best in terms of readability. Personally, I feel like the fourth method would be easiest and fastest so I don't need to create any references to the Viewport and it's clear that I'm referring to something that is global. It seems like it's taking out the "middleman", but then you have to import the XNA graphics library to every class that uses the Viewport.

What do you guys think?

Comment: Your question implies that there is a significant cost associated with typing `using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics` at the top of a class file.  This cost is small at design time, negligible at compile time, and *zero* at run time.

Comment: @phoog Ahh, so then my question is using a reference to property in the XNA library (or any library for that matter), like a private field in a classes declarations that references that property, slower than calling the property directly when it's needed?

Comment: The answer depends on the cost of calling the specific property in question. A property is syntactic sugar for a get method and/or a set method, so the cost of calling a property can be arbitrarily large. In practice, most properties wrap a private field; these calls may be inlined by the JIT compiler, making the cost zero. If the call to such a property getter is *not* inlined, the cost is still be fairly negligible. Standard advice would be to profile your application, and only cache the property value if you find that calls to the property getter consume a large amount of resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it depends on your design.  If this is just a simple, one-off application, I'd go with your first example.  You have a single viewport, none of your classes are dependent on the `GraphicsDevice` or however you decide to manage that viewport.

Storing the single object there and referencing it in your code will be fast; it's just a field reference so they don't come much faster than that.  Calling `GraphicsDevice.Viewport` every time, *especially* since it's a property means you'll be running a property getter method *every single time* you want to access it.

EDIT: If you want to quickly throw in a property wrapper on `Game.Viewport` (instead of a field) so you can track access (say for logging) temporarily, then you're free to do it this way.  If you choose the latter with `GraphicsDevice.Viewport`, you have to do it every place in your code where you call it (code duplication).

If this is for a more reusable library, *if it makes sense* to restrict access to your Viewport to only the relevant classes, or want to separate your dependency to `Game`, passing it down via constructors as dependency injection can be worthwhile, especially when it comes to unit testing.

I wouldn't even consider option 2 (evaluating `GraphicsDevice.Viewport` for each class as a private field).  At the very least you could wrap it with your own reusable static class (which is what you're doing with `Game`)

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response! So if I were to use the first example in which I had the single public Viewport reference, each time I called that reference, wouldn't calling that reference simply tell it to call the property getter method each time anyway? And on the same line of thought, does this mean properties have more overhead than fields since they need to run getter/setter methods?

Comment: If it's a `readonly` field, then there is no property getter overhead.  In general, the overhead with properties is often negligible; if you cannot use a `readonly` field and want to expose data, you're almost always better off using a getter and setter.  Typically you'd only want to trim that away if you are having some serious performance tweaking (which might be applicable for a game) but it's rarely, rarely, rarely the cause of performance issues.